# Django serving static pages from Sphinx

Tags: python, html, django, python-sphinx

I have a large group of static html pages that I've generated from sphinx, and I'd like to show them on my Django site. I can connect to at least one page by putting the html/ folder form sphinx in a templates directory inside my app, and changing the urls.py file to include

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")
```

Then it finds the index.html file inside myapp/templates/html. However, none of the internal links work (it'll try to redirect through Django and give me a 404 error). Also, the static files won't load in (Sphinx generates a _static folder, and even though I put that in the myapp directory, and the Chrome network tab tells me it's trying to load the css from myapp/_static, still nothing).

Is there any way to make all the links relative to each other inside this project? Alternatively, can I get Django to just serve up the whole project as static pages?

It looks like FlatPages is *almost* what I'm looking for, but I have more than just a title and content in these pages.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should **not** be using Django to serve essentially static files. This is what your webserver is for.

If you are using Apache, you can use the `<directory>` directive to serve these files alongside your Django routes.

Comment: Though it is legitimate to use Django in conjunction with your webserver to hide private static files behind auth. Nginx X-Accel or the like.